# When are we not allowed to replaced $\sin{x} $ , $\tan{x}$... by $x$ in a limit where $x\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

In what situation, can we not replace for example $e^x$ with $x$ when  when $x\to 0$, in a limit.

Sorry if the question is extremely vague , English is not my native language. Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't do replacements like these. Instead use standard limits and rules. If you see such replacement being done in some book then it is a case of omitting certain intermediate steps.

Comment: $e^x$ and $x$ are never equal !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the Taylor theorem.

Basically, we say that $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + g(x)$ with $g(x)$ negligible in 0.

We replace $sin(x)$ and $tan(x)$ because we know their expansion.

It turns out we also know the Taylor expansion of $exp(x) = 1 + x + g(x)$ in 0.

So you can replace $e^x$ by $1+x$ providing you don't need the higher order terms.

Comment: Can you pleas give a example where the higher order term is needed in a limit where $x\to 0$?.

Comment: $lim_0 \frac{exp(x) - 1 - x}{x^2}$ requires you to know the higher order term to be computed.

Comment: My question is , if get a function for example $$\lim_{x\to 0} \bigg( \frac{1+\tan{x}}{1+\sin{x}} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{\sin{x}}}$$ I can replace $\tan{x}$ and $\sin{x}$ with $x$ and i will get $$\lim_{x\to 0}  1^{\frac{1}{\sin{x}}}$$ which is $=1$

Comment: Yes, you can because the higher order terms are neglectible.

Comment: Thank  you are a legend , you may have saved me from failing my exam which is in 2 days

Answer (score 2):

Well, at least in the example which the OP pointed out in comment to @PackSciences answer
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1 + \tan x}{1 + \sin x} \right)^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}
$$
one is not allowed to just replace $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ with $x$ and end up with
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} 1^{\frac{1}{\sin x}} = 1.
$$

The right way to find such limits is to use second remarkable limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1 + \tan x}{1 + \sin x} \right)^{\frac{1}{\sin x}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \left( 1 + \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{1 + \sin x} \right)^{\frac{1}{\sin x}} =
$$
$$
= \lim_{x\to 0} \left( 1 + \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{1 + \sin x} \right)^{\frac{1+\sin x}{ (\tan x - \sin x)} \cdot \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin x(1+\sin x)}} = 
$$
$$
= \exp \left\{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin x(1+\sin x)} \right\} =e^0 = 1.
$$

If one were allowed to just replace $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ with $x$ then limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1 + \tan x}{1 + \sin x} \right)^{\frac{1}{\sin^3 x}}
$$
would be equal to $1$.

But, as the following computation shows
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1 + \tan x}{1 + \sin x} \right)^{\frac{1}{\sin^3 x}} 
= \exp \left\{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{\sin^3 x(1+\sin x)} \right\} =
$$
$$
= \exp \left\{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{\cos x} \right\} =
$$
$$
= \exp \left\{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{2\cos x} \right\} = \sqrt{e},
$$
which is clearly not equal to $1$.

So, things are actually a little more complicated :)

The rule of thumb here is that one can use equivalences when the limit involves product, without sums. For example, consider the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{\cos x}
$$

Here we can use equivalences
$$
\sin x \sim x, \cos x \sim 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}.
$$

One can always check himself rewriting this limit in the form
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{\cos x} =
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{\cos x \cdot x^2 / 2} \cdot \frac{x^2/2}{x^2} = 
$$
$$
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2 / 2} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\cos x} \cdot \frac{x^2/2}{x^2} = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to tell in advance just how many terms of the Maclaurin series you need. For example, to find $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\mathrm e^x-\cos x+2\ln(1+x)-3\sin x}{\tan x-x},$$you need to expand the functions up to the term in $x^3$. The best way of doing such problems, I've found, is to expand for a few terms, and then try it again with a few more terms if needed. If you write down too many terms, no harm is done other than wasting a bit of time.

As others have mentioned, replacing $\mathrm e^x$ by $x$ is completely wrong. The first approximation is $1+x$ near $x=0$; but you will have to expand $\mathrm e^x$ as far as $1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3$ in the above example, which I suggest you try.

Answer (score 0):

Let us work on an example.

Obviously, $x$ (green) and $e^x-1$ (blue) are not the same function. But for small $x$, $e^x-1\sim x$, they tend to zero "the same way", so that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{x}=1.$$

But if we consider the difference $e^x-1-x$, there is a nonzero residue (magenta), that we can approximate with a parabola. The parabola coefficient is given by the ratio (black)

$$\frac{(e^x-1)-x}{x^2},$$ the limit of which at $0$ can be show to be $\dfrac12$.

This is to be contrasted with

$$\frac{x-x}{x^2}=0$$ and this shows that $e^x-1$ and $x$ can behave differently in a limit. It is explained by the "amplifying" effect of the division by $x^2$.

[image]